# Plotando Gráficos ggplot dentro de loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou querendo criar uma for usando ggplot:

```
Carteira<-cbind(A, B, C,D,E,F)
```

A, B, C,D,E,F sao dados no formato "zoo".

Meu código é:

```
 for(i in 1:6){

  ggplot(Carteira[,i], aes(Carteira[,i])) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..), 
                 breaks=seq(-20, 20, by = 2), 
                 col="black", 
                 fill="blue", 
                 alpha = .1) + 
  geom_density(col=1) + 
  labs(title="Histogram ") +
  labs(x="Returns", y="Count") +
  xlim(c(-20,20))
}
```

O curioso é que nada acontece. Nem menssagem de erro aparece.
Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 7):

O problema é que você está dentro do `loop` então você tem que pedir explicitamente para dar print no gráfico do `ggplot`.

Por exemplo, no comando abaixo, nada vai aparecer:

```
for(i in 1:6) i
```

Já se você colocar `print`, os números aparecem:

```
for(i in 1:6) print(i)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
```

É a mesma coisa com o gráfico do `ggplot`. Por exemplo, o comando abaixo não plota nenhum gráfico:

```
for(i in 1:6) ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()
```

Já colocando o print os 6 gráficos aparecem:

```
for(i in 1:6) print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point())
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara tenta adicionar um print nesse seu ggplot:

```
     for(i in 1:6){
    
#print foi adicionado na plotagem do histograma para percorrer os índices

      print(ggplot(Carteira[,i], aes(Carteira[,i])) + 
      geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..), 
                     breaks=seq(-20, 20, by = 2), 
                     col="black", 
                     fill="blue", 
                     alpha = .1) + 
      geom_density(col=1) + 
      labs(title="Histogram ") +
      labs(x="Returns", y="Count") +
      xlim(c(-20,20)))
    }
```